# I want to change the modal of confirm but I don't know where to start from

Tags: javascript

This is the code for the confirm.

```
             <td><a href="source.php?admin_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>&username= 
                 <?php echo $_SESSION['admin_username']; ?>" 
                      data-toggle="tooltip" 
                      data-placement="top" 
                      title="Delete"> 
                      <i id="del" class="mdi mdi-close"></i> </a> 
             </td>
```

This is the script for the confirm.

```
const deleteIcon = document.getElementById("del");
deleteIcon.addEventListener("click",(e) => { 
   const confirmVar = confirm("Do you want to proceed? ");
   if(confirmVar){
        return true;
   }else{
        return false;
   }
   
})
```

This is the modal where I want to change the default confirm of javascript.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="confirmModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="confirmModalLabel">Please validate!</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Do you want to proceed?.
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="btnSave" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple things to fix. Your link wasn't set up right, because it was a regular link (which would go directly to it's href thus ignoring the `id='del'` icon inside with the event listener). What is needed is to make that link a button which opens the confirm modal. When the modal confirmation button is clicked, then you can go to the link.

I have set this up so that you can have multiple delete buttons on the page, each will need their own data-href attribute.

The delete link became a button that triggers the modal. The modal has the confirm button which, when clicked, finds the data-href of the delete button that opened the modal.

```js
let goToDeleteLink = ''
let btnSave = document.getElementById('btnSave')
btnSave.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('go to ' + goToDeleteLink);
})

let btnDeletes = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-button')
btnDeletes.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // store the current delete link
    goToDeleteLink = e.target.dataset.href

  })
})
```

```html
<html><head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <button data-href="source.php?admin_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>&username=<?php echo $_SESSION['admin_username']; ?>" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#confirmModal" class="delete-button">
        <i class="mdi mdi-close"></i> close </button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="confirmModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="confirmModalLabel">Please validate!</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Do you want to proceed?.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button id="btnSave" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```